# Getting cors error while trying to make HTTP GET request

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a http get request, I am getting on network tab CORS-ERROR.

I am running my client on live-server (http://127.0.0.1:5000/client/contactAdmin.html)
and the api I am trying to reach to is (http://localhost:5000/api/form/contactAdmin)

```
app.use('/api/form', formRoute);

router.get('/contactAdmin', async (req, res) => {
  const allForms = await Form.find({});

  return res.status(200).json({ allForms });
});
```

client:

```
const renderForms = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      'http://localhost:5000/api/form/contactAdmin',
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      }
    );
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

renderForms();
```

Network tab:
[image]

Comment: are u using express.js server for your backend?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mention it

Comment: "I am trying to make a http get request, I am getting on network tab CORS-ERROR." — That's expected. Have you done any research on what CORS is and how it works? Did you have an actual question?

Comment: Maybe I'm not a "professional" like you?
I am not trying to lie, just facing a problem I didn't faced before..